# How to separate HTML output field into 2 separate fields instead of one amalgamated field

Tags: html, input, html-table, output

Currently this code gives me the result I want numerically, however the two possible outputs show up as one long number, but I would like to be able to separate them into their own tables.

```
<form
 oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(300);y.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(400);">
  <input name="a" value="" type="text">
<output name="x" for="a b"><br>
  </output><output name="y" for="a b"></output></form>
```

I tried putting each of the fields into a table like

```
  <form
 oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(300);y.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(400);">
  <output for="a b" name="y"></output>
  <table style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" border="1"
 cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="a" value="" type="text"></td>
      </tr>
<tr>
<td><output name="x" for="a b"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><output name="y" for="a b"></td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

But that only puts the input field into a table and one output and two blank table spaces....I am lost. Help? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work fine if you remove the two scraggling output fields under form, like so:

```
<form
    oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(300);y.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(400);">
        <table style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" border="1"
        cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="a" value="" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><output name="x" for="a b"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><output name="y" for="a b"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Within a form, a name can only be used once, so removing that scraggling  element with a name of 'y' at the top (but outside of the table) should remove the duplicate 'y' elements within the form letting the "oninput" code find the right output field.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely makes sense. I really appreciate your help.